# How can I skip authentication in a single test with a fixture in Fast API together with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, fixtures

I have built authentication similar to what is described in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/). So I have this dependency copied from there:

```py
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(username=username)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = get_user(fake_users_db, username=token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user
```

Which I use in a set of endpoints, for example, in the other example of the documentation, for `User` I have `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` and `GET ALL`.

The only method which does not require authentication is the POST method to create a new user.

I want to be able to define unit tests that verify the method can not be accessed without authentication and also I want to skip the authentication completely when I'm focusing on the content of the method.

Therefore I used the override functionality in a fixture. For example for this test:

`test_user.py`

```py
def test_create_user(test_db, create_user, user, skip_authentication):
    """
    Verify a user can be created and retrieved
    """
    response = client.post(
        "/api/v1/users/",
        json=create_user,
    )

    # Assert creation
    assert response.status_code == 200, response.text
    data = response.json()
    assert "id" in data
    user_id = data["id"]
    del data["id"]
    assert data == user

    # Assert get user
    response = client.get(f"/api/v1/users/{user_id}")
    assert response.status_code == 200, response.text
    data = response.json()
    assert user_id == data["id"]
    del data["id"]
    assert data == user
```

`conftest.py`

```
@pytest.fixture
def skip_authentication() -> None:

    def get_current_user():
        pass
    app.dependency_overrides[get_current_active_user] = get_current_user
```

And this seems to work to remove the authentication, but it removes it in all tests, not just in the ones with the fixture `skip_authentication`.

How can I limit it to only the tests I want?

Comment: Have you tried with `mock`?

Comment: Split your `client` fixture into two - one with `client` and `app.dependency_overrides[get_current_user] = None`, one named `skip_authentication_client` which depend on the `client` fixture and then configure the dependency override. I.e. you reset it to no override when not needed, and set it when needed. But if the endpoint _does not require authentication_, why does it check `get_current_user`? If the test fails with authentication required, wouldn't a regular client also fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comment of @MatsLindh I was able to make it work. I'm not sure if is the ideal solution but works for me.

I created two fixtures one for authenticated user and the other one for the other tests:

`conftest.py`

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    """
    Return an API Client
    """
    app.dependency_overrides = {}
    return TestClient(app)

@pytest.fixture
def client_authenticated():
    """
    Returns an API client which skips the authentication
    """
    def skip_auth():
        pass
    app.dependency_overrides[get_current_active_user] = skip_auth
    return TestClient(app)
```

Then I was able to test my normal tests and also verify the authentication with:

```py
def test_premissions_user(client, test_db, create_user):
    """
    Verify that not logged in users can not access the user functions excluding create
    """
    # Create user
    response = client.post(
        "/api/v1/users/",
        json=create_user
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200, response.text

    # Get all users
    response = client.get(
        "/api/v1/users/",
    )
    assert response.status_code == 401, response.text
    
    # Get user 1
    response = client.get(
        "/api/v1/users/1",
    )
    assert response.status_code == 401, response.text        
    
    # Delete user 1
    response = client.get(
        "/api/v1/users/1",
    )
    assert response.status_code == 401, response.text    
    
    # Modify user 1
    response = client.delete(
        "/api/v1/users/1",
    )
    assert response.status_code == 401, response.text

def test_premissions_user_authenticated(client_authenticated, test_db, create_user):
    """
    Verify that not logged in users can not access the user functions excluding create
    """
    # Create user
    response = client_authenticated.post(
        "/api/v1/users/",
        json=create_user
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200, response.text

    # Get all users
    response = client_authenticated.get(
        "/api/v1/users/",
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200, response.text
    
    # Get user 1
    response = client_authenticated.get(
        "/api/v1/users/1",
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200, response.text        
    
    # Delete user 1
    response = client_authenticated.get(
        "/api/v1/users/1",
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200, response.text    
    
    # Modify user 1
    response = client_authenticated.delete(
        "/api/v1/users/1",
    )
    assert response.status_code == 204, response.text
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created the [pytest-fastapi-deps](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-fastapi-deps/) library, which allows easy definition and cleanup of FastAPI dependencies.

Use it like so and it would only affect a single test:

```py
def test_create_user(test_db, create_user, user, fastapi_dep):
    """
    Verify a user can be created and retrieved
    """
    def skip_auth():
        pass
    with fastapi_dep(app).override({get_current_active_user: skip_auth}):
        response = client.post(
            "/api/v1/users/",
            json=create_user,
        )

        # Assert creation
        assert response.status_code == 200, response.text
        data = response.json()
        assert "id" in data
        user_id = data["id"]
        del data["id"]
        assert data == user

        # Assert get user
        response = client.get(f"/api/v1/users/{user_id}")
        assert response.status_code == 200, response.text
        data = response.json()
        assert user_id == data["id"]
        del data["id"]
        assert data == user
```